Can I have a SUM of quantity from one table, but subtract from that quantity first based on another table?
Summary
I am attempting to get the total quantity of loans for a specific product for each date in a range - but want to subtract from the total when order_item_id has specific meta data.
Table: loans



loan_id
loan_date
order_id
order_item_id
product_id
quantity




1
2024-01-01
1
1
1
1


2
2024-01-02
1
2
1
1


3
2024-01-01
2
3
1
1



Table: order_meta



meta_id
order_item_id
meta_key
meta_value




1
1
returned
yes


2
1
othermeta
123


3
2
othermeta
345


4
3
othermeta
123



My Current Query
SELECT SUM( quantity ) AS total, loan_date, product_id FROM loans WHERE product_id = 1 AND loan_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-02' GROUP BY loan_date ORDER BY loan_date ASC;




total
loan_date
product_id




2
2024-01-01
1


1
2024-01-02
1



How can I reduce the total based on a meta key/value?
In my current query the total is 2 on 2024-01-01, but one of those has been returned and therefore I do not want the total to include that, I want to reduce the total if the order_item_id has a order_meta table row for meta_key = returned and meta_value = yes. How can I do this?
I've been reading up but struggling to find a solution, it feels like I need a LEFT JOIN of some description of the order_meta, something like this:
SELECT SUM( loans.quantity ) AS total, loans.loan_date, loans.product_id, loans.order_item_id FROM loans
LEFT JOIN order_meta
ON loans.order_item_id = order_meta.order_item_id
WHERE loans.product_id = 1 AND loans.loan_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-02'
-- THEN MAYBE HERE A "IF meta_key of returned exists and is yes" but unsure how to do it
GROUP BY loans.loan_date ORDER BY loans.loan_date ASC

I've tried a few different queries but was getting syntax or errors in relation to the grouping.
Data for testing
Fiddle
CREATE TABLE loans (
  loan_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  loan_date date,
  order_id BIGINT,
  order_item_id BIGINT,
  product_id BIGINT,
  quantity BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE order_meta (
  meta_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  order_item_id BIGINT,
  meta_key varchar(255),
  meta_value longtext
);

INSERT INTO loans(loan_date, order_id, order_item_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('2024-01-01',1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO loans(loan_date, order_id, order_item_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('2024-01-02',1,2,1,1);
INSERT INTO loans(loan_date, order_id, order_item_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('2024-01-01',2,3,1,1);

INSERT INTO order_meta(order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (1,'returned','yes');
INSERT INTO order_meta(order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (1,'othermeta','123');
INSERT INTO order_meta(order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (2,'othermeta','345');
INSERT INTO order_meta(order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (3,'othermeta','123');

SELECT * FROM loans;
SELECT * FROM order_meta;
SELECT SUM( quantity ) AS total, loan_date, product_id FROM loans WHERE product_id = 1 AND loan_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-02' GROUP BY loan_date ORDER BY loan_date ASC;


Amending your query to include an existence check
SELECT SUM( quantity ) AS total, loan_date, product_id 
FROM loans 
WHERE product_id = 1 AND loan_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-02' 
      and not exists (select 1 from order_meta om 
                      where om.order_item_id = loans.order_item_id and meta_key = 'returned' and meta_value = 'yes')
GROUP BY loan_date ORDER BY loan_date ASC;

